# WSDL - How to connect to webservice from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client

I need to connect my java project to a web service, described by a WSDL file. I'm using eclipse indigo and I must code some java classes to test it. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't connect Eclipse to anything. You write tests that connect to your web service. You haven't told us what web service development package you are using. All of them include a client side.

Most likely, you can use the JAX-WS API to create a client. You can run the ws2java or wsdl2java command line tool from your web services stack to make a client API, and then you just write code to call it.